# Can't call a function from js file imported as type module

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am writing my Javascript files in ES6 using module imports. Using type='module' is now supported on most modern browsers to allow for proper parsing of import statements. 
    script type="module
https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module

I built an HTML select element were onchange() calls a function from one of my module files using
    select onchange="someFunction()"
but an error is always thrown saying the function is not defined when the on change event occurs. 
I tested the same function inline and also without using the type="module" with no issues as expected.

Is this a bug? Does it have to do with module scripts being deferred by default? Am I missing something simple?

I understand I could avoid this issue by using Webpack or a framework but I really wanted to try and use just vanilla javascript without any extras. I believe also creating this select element in the js then attaching to the dom would also solve the issue as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules don't create globals. Everything is scoped within the module.

If you want to bind an event handler, then do it from inside the module using `addEventListener` and not using an `onXxxxx` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to use function when use script with type module

```
            <button onclick="import('/modules/script.js').then(o=> o.showdialog())">
```

and use export in script.js

```
export function showdialog() {}
```